# PHPMailer sometimes send mails sometimes not.use gmail smtp

Tags: php, phpmailer, google-workspace, dedicated-server

i am using phpmailerclass with my website forms and its working 100% fine and i could not see any error also sending emails fine but sometimes rare miss send email. when form miss send email behaviour is like when click on submit button miss send email but on second try click submit send email. not always like that email send perfect on first try but when problem start need to second try then send email. i have Gsuite business account google side setting correct too. why sometimes missing ?

```
include("phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$fmail="username@domain.com";

// start email1
$mail = new PHPMailer();
    
$mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->port=587;
$mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = "username@domain.com"; 
$mail->Password = "passwordhere"; 
$mail->FromName = "companyName";
$mail->SetFrom($fmail);
$mail->AddAddress($mailaddress);
//$mail->AddCC("companyname@gmailcom.com");

$filename11=$fileName1;
if($filename11!="")
{
$dir1= uploadFilePathAdmin.$orderNo."-".$filename11;
$mail->AddAttachment($dir1);
}

$filename12=$fileName2;
if($filename12!="")
{
$dir2= uploadFilePathAdmin.$orderNo."-".$filename12;
$mail->AddAttachment($dir2);
}

$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->Subject = "".stripslashes($designName)."-".$orderNo." - PO: ".$ponumber."";
$mail->Body = $MESSAGE; 
$mail->AltBody = $MESSAGE; 

$mail->Send();

// start email2
$mail2 = new PHPMailer();
$mail2->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
$mail2->port=587;
$mail2->SMTPSecure='tls';
$mail2->IsSMTP(); 
$mail2->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail2->Username = "username@domain.com"; 
$mail2->Password = "passwordhere"; 
$mail2->FromName = "companyName";

$mail2->SetFrom($emailee);
$mail2->AddAddress($fmail);
$mail2->AddReplyTo($mailaddress);

$filename21=$fileName1;
if($filename21!="")
{
$dir33= uploadFilePathAdmin.$orderNo."-".$filename21;
$mail2->AddAttachment($dir33);
}

$filename22=$fileName2;
if($filename22!="")
{
$dir22= uploadFilePathAdmin.$orderNo."-".$filename22;
$mail2->AddAttachment($dir22);
}

$mail2->IsHTML(true); 
$mail2->Subject = "".$designName."-".$orderNo." - PO: ".$ponumber."";
$mail2->Body = $MESSAGE; 
$mail2->AltBody = $MESSAGE; 
$mail2->Send();
```

Comment: i have added code for smtp debugging below but no output is coming on screen why also debugging is not giving out ?
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; //Alternative to above constant

Comment: One (unimportant) typo: `$mail->port=587;` should be `$mail->Port=587;`; PHP is case sensitive for property names. You're using a very old version of PHPMailer, and you have no error checking at all. Look at the examples provided with PHPMailer. Also, you don't need a new instance of PHPMailer to send a second message; It's much faster to enable keepalive and send both in the same SMTP session.

Comment: finally i got the output on debug dont know what the reason
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
2020-07-30 21:29:30 2 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
2020-07-30 21:40:26 2 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP b17sm822395otj.73 - gsmtp

Comment: Read the guide. It looks like your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP.

Comment: i have checked from server csf firewall outbound port 465 also 587 are enabled. how it can be block as you say.

Comment: That may be the settings on your server alone – your hosting provider may still be blocking you further upstream. Use telnet to test - it’s described in the guide